# AngularUI Bootstrap datepicker maxDate does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I forked the Plunker code from the AngularUI Bootstrap pages (the Datepicker example). I wanted to implement a max date range so you can only select a date in a certain period. You can find the Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/vBrgyC20FBEUzuoprhlh?p=preview

Somehow, the maxDate attribute does not seem to be working while the minDate one does. Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong here or if it's just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two date pickers in there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML in the plunker

```
<datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="showWeeks"></datepicker>
```

What it should have been

```
<datepicker min="minDate" max="maxDate" show-weeks="showWeeks"></datepicker>
```

Seems you just forgot to add the max-attribute?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't show up for you (I think I edited it afterwards), but the max attribute was there from the start. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to save it? I added the max="maxDate" part and it worked. Anyway, looks like you got it working now?

Answer (score 0):

```
<datepicker min="minDate" max="maxDate" show-weeks="showWeeks"></datepicker>
```

Worked for me as well, i was struggling with the attribute max-date", Thanks ivarni for your answer